# Deploy React App github pages с собственными настройками Webpack

Tags: reactjs, github-pages

Всем доброго времени суток! У меня есть готовое React-приложение. Настройку Webpack производил самостоятельно, то бишь не пользовался стандартом create-react-app, где, говорят, deploy github pages работает идеально. По бороздил интернет поисках ответа и кое что нарыл. Свое приложение на githab pages я запускаю, но с некоторыми багами, которые не могу никак понять.

Теперь по порядку: я писал приложение созданного на github и комитил туда изменения пока не закончил. То есть локально и удаленно оно связано. Когда закончил установил npm i gh-pages -DE. И прописал настройки в package.json: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Webpack.config и структура проекта выглядит таким образом:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее прописал npm run deploy, он собрал bundle.js и ответил что gh-pages - Published. Но ссылку в консоле не была указана, где по материалам изучения у всех она была.

Я двинулся дальше. Внес изменения **npm add .** , закомитил **npm commit -m 'add'** , из запушил **npm push original master**. В github настройках проекта и увидел что gh-pages залетел. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нажимаю на ссылку, проект открывается. Но не так как надо. У меня в приложении есть **404 route страница**, где есть ссылка на главную route страницу с **path="/"**.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я нажимаю туда, а в адресной строке вот такая абракадабра

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если нажать ctrl+F5, то страница будет не найдена. И еще есть проблема с тегами img. У них есть, допустим у одного,  **src="../img/logo.svg"**. И он не отображается, хотя в css стилях есть такое и оно почему то отображается.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я даже не знаю в чем беда, и вот еще index.html

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Кароче, надо брать **HashRouter** вместо **Router**, и img давать адрес без всяких **../img/logo**. Настройки package.json вставил такие

"homepage": "http://Aleksey-Shtr1h.github.io/1106325-six-cities-4",
"predeploy": "npm run build",
"deploy": "gh-pages -d public",
"build": "webpack",

сделал деплой и залил в удаленное репо. Вроде работает, только warning на HashRouter кидает.

Comment: Теперь баги с history